# textfield with scrollable in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I implemented textfield with multiline and scrollable in y-direction. But it works weird as shown in figure below. If I add one text after other in multiline fashion, as soon as I reach the keyboard pop-up the text at top is still visible it just dont scroll till end. 
[image]
[image]

As it can be seen in first image if I scroll it starts going at top of the screen and in second image it just don't show the text written at end. Any suggestions on this will be helpful. Thanks

I even used the DataChangedListener but I think that's not issue here.

```
dataTextField = (TextField) uib.findByName(DESIGNER_NAME_TEXT_FIELD, container);
        dataTextField.setMaxSize(model.getMaxLength());
        if (model.isMultiLine()) {
            dataTextField.setSingleLineTextArea(false);
            dataTextField.setRows(2);
        } else {
            dataTextField.setSingleLineTextArea(true);
        }
dataTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (dataTextField != null) {
                    if (dataTextField.getText().compareTo(model.getData().toString()) != 0) {
                        updateModel(dataTextField.getText());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        public void updateModel(String text) {
    synchronized(syncLock) {
        model.onUserDataEntered(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by scrollable, how is it placed into the Container to occupy the full screen like that?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, Thanks for your reply. Scrollable in the sense, the scrollvisible is true in this case. It's just normal TextField but it grows by content. 
Am I doing anything wrong here? As I want to Implement mulitline textfield which needs to scroll as the text grows.

Comment: Text components need a parent to be scrollable so the question is what's the parent of the text field? How is it configured? What's the layout?

Comment: I've filed this in the issue tracker here https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2543

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, is there any solution for this? I tried different ways but I still get the same way. Thanks

Comment: I suggest following up with Steve in the issue tracker. Help him reproduce this so he can address it.